# Calculating the gravity gradient of a black hole

Tags: gravity, black-holes, tidal-effect

Given a black hole of, say, $10^8 \odot$ (solar masses), how can I calculate the gravity gradient ($\frac{\Delta g}{m}$?) at a given distance from it?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90591